# Can I replace the default login screen for the Pantheon Greeter?

Tags: login, lightdm, pantheon

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and I'd like to know if I can replace the default login screen (Light-DM) for the one used on ELementary OS (Phantheon Greeter). If possible without installing the rest of the Elementary OS desktop.

[image: Elementary OS Login Screen]

Comment: did somebody tried this for 13.10 ?

Comment: for Ubuntu 14.04 refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/512090/how-to-get-pantheon-greeter-on-ubuntu-14-04-instead-of-lightdm/682844#682844)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you only need to Install `pantheon-greeter` and change the LightDM conf file like so:

- To get `pantheon-greeter` you'll need to add this PPA, open a terminal and type:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pantheon-greeter elementary-theme fonts-open-sans-elementary fonts-raleway-elementary
  ```
- Then open gedit as root, type `gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
- Change the line *greeter-session=* to look like this `greeter-session=pantheon-greeter`
- Log out

Comment: How does it look?

Comment: @Uri; I installed the package successfully, but the login screen looks way different from the image above (see here http://goo.gl/kP9aG). Can I fix it?

Comment: Alright, install these packages and log out and check if it looks correctly now: `elementary-theme fonts-open-sans fonts-raleway`.

Comment: I have done what was recommended. I have added greeter-session=pantheon-greeter, but ubuntu is still booting into unity, and not greeter. I have restarted the machine too. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

Everyone is right but! Think it may be better to stay w/ Stable

Also try:

```
https://launchpad.net/~philip.scott/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-tweaks
```

This has bunch of tweaks under System Settings → Personal → Tweaks

[image]