# How to install pantheon-greeter in 13.04 Raring?

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, lightdm, pantheon

Refer here: [QUESTION](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257470/can-i-replace-the-default-login-screen-for-the-pantheon-greeter)

Those are the exact step I did in my install - a raring x64 server install + all needed xorg packages to run a GUI + MATE 1.6.

Basic lightdm + unity-greeter is flawless, as well as the other lightdm greeter available under ubuntu, and I also use Gala window manager from the eOs ppa, but pantheon-greeter fails to start from lightdm.

I am able to run it from a terminal window within a session, just never from lightdm - it always shows the message "unable to start job".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's sad but I'll answer it myself ...

The packages in the other question was incomplete hence it's crashing. I had to add 2 additional packages - elementary-icon-theme and notify-osd-icons-elementary. Refered to this [BUG REPORT](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-greeter/+bug/1181868). notify-osd-icons-elementary wasnt actually part of the bug report but itwas recommended by apt-get so I included it.

So the more complete instruction would be

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pantheon-greeter elementary-theme fonts-open-sans fonts-raleway elementary-icon-theme notify-osd-icons-elementary
```

Comment: Studied it more, you can get away with even less packages as follows: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pantheon-greeter elementary-icon-theme notify-osd-icons-elementary