# How to get Pantheon Greeter on Ubuntu 14.04 instead of Unity Greeter

Tags: 14.04, gnome, lightdm, lock-screen, pantheon

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, how can I replace the lockscreen with the one on Elementary Luna (Pantheon-Greeter). Thank You!!

Edit: Can anyone do it and confirm it works completely?

Answer (score 1):

To install `Pantheon Greeter` on Ubuntu `14.04`,Open terminal and run the commands:

Since  libgranite3 (>= 0.2.0) missing in 14.04,so we need the following PPA as well.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install pantheon-greeter
```

Note:
After installation remove ppa's:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

Note: Tested and working. refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682828/i-cant-install-pantheon-greeter-in-ubuntu-14-04/682842#682842)

For settings I found a similar link refer [Can I replace the default login screen for the Pantheon Greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257470/can-i-replace-the-default-login-screen-for-the-pantheon-greeter)

Answer (score 0):

Add elemantaryrepositary to ubuntu.
It is just do not enough install Panthon greeter.
Install all other software needed.
Use below command to install them.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pantheon-greeter elementary-theme fonts-open-sans fonts-raleway elementary-icon-theme notify-osd-icons-elementary
```

open gedit as root, type gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Change the line greeter-session= to look like this greeter-session=pantheon-greeter

Refer this link-[Can I replace the default login screen for the Pantheon Greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257470/can-i-replace-the-default-login-screen-for-the-pantheon-greeter)

Comment: It says E: Package 'fonts-open-sans' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'fonts-raleway' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'notify-osd-icons-elementary' has no installation candidate

Comment: Does other software installed without any problem?

Comment: yes, the pantheon-greeter works, but it doesnt look like what elementary os has completely

Comment: fonts-open-sans fonts-raleway are not available

Comment: Add the stable repository. I think it will solve the problem  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pantheon-greeter elementary-theme fonts-open-sans fonts-raleway elementary-icon-theme notify-osd-icons-elementary

Comment: it still does not exist

Comment: Try to download and manually install fonts

Comment: It bricked my installation and I couldn't boot anymore, can you confirm that it works for you?

Comment: What are the software you installed before your problem happened?

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can get the greeter from Luna on to ubuntu 14.04 using that repository. It will point to the Trusty files, so what you'll get is the new pantheon-greeter being developed for elementary os Freya