# I can't install Pantheon Greeter in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lightdm

I want to install pantheon Greeter from Elementary OS in Ubuntu 14.04. When I follow every tutorial on the web I get it in the Terminal:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 

pantheon-greeter : Depends: libgranite3 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*
```

What is going on?

Comment: "every tutorial" will you please provide link of tutorial you followed?

Comment: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/512090/how-to-get-pantheon-greeter-on-ubuntu-14-04-instead-of-lightdm] This is exactly like the other ones I saw.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: please accept it as answer if it solved your problem...comment if not solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my search  libgranite3 (>= 0.2.0) not available for 14.04

refer [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgranite0)

so before installing `pantheon`  we need to add the following `PPA`(that will install  libgranite3):

Open terminal and run the following commands in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-greeter
```

**Note**: Remove the PPAs after installation

For reference [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512090/how-to-get-pantheon-greeter-on-ubuntu-14-04-instead-of-lightdm/682844#682844)

---

**RESULT AFTER TESTING**

```
sudo apt-get install pantheon-greeter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apport-hooks-elementary contractor libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libcairo2
  libgail-3-0 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libgranite-common libgranite3
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-common libpango-1.0-0 libpango1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0
  libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
 numlockx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apport-hooks-elementary contractor libgranite-common libgranite3 numlockx
  pantheon-greeter
 The following packages will be upgraded:
  libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libcairo2 libgail-3-0 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin
 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-common libpango-1.0-0 libpango1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0
  libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
    15 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 119 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.5 MB of archives.
   After this operation, 29.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: It says the same. I installed libgranite from the link, but it doesn't work still.

Comment: @Yosef see updated answer..I tested to download working!

Comment: Thank you! The problem was here: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches`

Comment: @Yosef yes...btw remove the ppa s after installing.